# Jlink can't put Derby into the runtime?

Tags: maven, javafx, jdbc, derby, jlink

UPDATE:

Maybe it is better if I rephrase the question: How to tell Jlink to put the java.sql or derby into the runtime?
Meantime I tried it with a 'jlinkVerbose' option in the pom file and as a result I can see this after a 'mvn clean javafx:jlink':

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AdventureGameEngine 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ AdventureGameEngine ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/sysadmin/NetBeansProjects/AdventureGameEngine/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.3:jlink (default-cli) @ AdventureGameEngine ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 45 resources
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /home/sysadmin/NetBeansProjects/AdventureGameEngine/target/classes
[INFO] /home/sysadmin/NetBeansProjects/AdventureGameEngine/src/main/java/com/mycompany/adventuregameengine/FXMLDocumentController.java: /home/sysadmin/NetBeansProjects/AdventureGameEngine/src/main/java/com/mycompany/adventuregameengine/FXMLDocumentController.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /home/sysadmin/NetBeansProjects/AdventureGameEngine/src/main/java/com/mycompany/adventuregameengine/FXMLDocumentController.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
com.mycompany.adventuregameengine file:///home/sysadmin/NetBeansProjects/AdventureGameEngine/target/classes/
java.base file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.base.jmod
java.datatransfer file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.datatransfer.jmod
java.desktop file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.desktop.jmod
java.logging file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.logging.jmod
java.prefs file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.prefs.jmod
java.scripting file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.scripting.jmod
java.sql file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.sql.jmod
java.transaction.xa file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.transaction.xa.jmod
java.xml file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.xml.jmod
javafx.base file:///home/sysadmin/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-base/11/javafx-base-11-linux.jar
javafx.controls file:///home/sysadmin/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-controls/11/javafx-controls-11-linux.jar
javafx.fxml file:///home/sysadmin/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-fxml/11/javafx-fxml-11-linux.jar
javafx.graphics file:///home/sysadmin/.m2/repository/org/openjfx/javafx-graphics/11/javafx-graphics-11-linux.jar
jdk.unsupported file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/jdk.unsupported.jmod

Providers:
  java.desktop provides java.net.ContentHandlerFactory used by java.base
  java.base provides java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider used by java.base
  java.desktop provides javax.print.PrintServiceLookup used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.print.StreamPrintServiceFactory used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiDeviceProvider used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiFileReader used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.midi.spi.MidiFileWriter used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.midi.spi.SoundbankReader used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileReader used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.sampled.spi.AudioFileWriter used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.sampled.spi.FormatConversionProvider used by java.desktop
  java.desktop provides javax.sound.sampled.spi.MixerProvider used by java.desktop
  java.logging provides jdk.internal.logger.DefaultLoggerFinder used by java.base
  java.desktop provides sun.datatransfer.DesktopDatatransferService used by java.datatransfer
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.176 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-17T11:01:49+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/84M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It still gives the 'BUILD SUCCESS' result and despite it says 'java.sql file:///usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/jmods/java.sql.jmod
', the java.sql is missing from the 'Providers:' section.

END of UPDATE.

I am working on a game in Java11 + JavaFX. The building tool is Maven. The IDE is Netbeans 11.

It is a modular project.

I use this manual: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans

The game compiles and runs smoothly, it can create/read/update the Derby DB when I start it in Netbeans via maven by 'clean javafx:run'.
When I want to create the runtime from terminal by 'mvn clean javafx:jlink' I get a 'BUILD SUCCESS' result too.
But when I try to start the launcher by 'target/adventuregame/bin/adventuregamelauncher' I get an error message:

```
Connection error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:advDB;create=true
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/com.mycompany.adventuregameengine/com/mycompany/adventuregameengine/FXMLDocument.fxml:15

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at com.mycompany.adventuregameengine@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.adventuregameengine.AdventureGame.start(AdventureGame.java:17)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.adventuregameengine@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.adventuregameengine.DB.<init>(DB.java:46)
    at com.mycompany.adventuregameengine@1.0-SNAPSHOT/com.mycompany.adventuregameengine.FXMLDocumentController.<init>(FXMLDocumentController.java:888)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application com.mycompany.adventuregameengine.AdventureGame
```

I checked the target/adventuregame/lib/classlist file and it seems to me that the problem is that the jdbc / derby classes are not included. It seems to me that the Jlink can not put the jdbc into the runtime, despite that this manual
https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-maven-plugin#javafxjlink-options
writes that 'The plugin includes by default: --module-path, --add-modules and -classpath options.'

Here is my module-info.java file:

```
module com.mycompany.adventuregameengine {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;
//    requires java.naming;
//    requires java.management;

    opens com.mycompany.adventuregameengine to javafx.fxml; //java.desktop, java.sql
    exports com.mycompany.adventuregameengine;
}
```

Before I posted I've checked the similar topics here on stackoverflow, and one suggested that including java.naming and java.management could help, I tried it but it doesn't.

Here is my pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>AdventureGameEngine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>--add-modules</arg>
                        <arg>java.sql</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
        
                    <launcher>adventuregamelauncher</launcher>
                    <jlinkImageName>adventuregame</jlinkImageName>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.adventuregameengine.AdventureGame</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried the 'compilerArgs' section, but it did not help.

Here is the section of my DB file what the error message refers to, but it must be OK since it runs properly via Netbeans, the problem is with the runtime.

```
public class DB {
    
    final String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    final String URL = "jdbc:derby:advDB;create=true";
    
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement createStatement = null;
    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = null;
    
    public DB(){
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
            System.out.println("There is a connection.");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Connection error: " + ex);
        }
        
        if (conn != null){
            try {
                createStatement = conn.createStatement(); //create a statement (auto)
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Statement error: " + ex);
            }
        }
        
        //is the database empty, so the program runs first time?
        try {
            dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "HERO", null); //capital letter!
            if(!rs.next()){
                createStatement.execute("create table hero(hp INT, score INT, currentRoom INT, vanBackpack boolean)");
                createStatement.execute("create table rooms(description varchar(200), eszakra INT, keletre INT, delre INT, nyugatra INT, fel INT, le INT, id INT)");
                createStatement.execute("create table items(roomnumber INT, name varchar(30), description varchar(200), felveheto boolean, vizsgal varchar(200), pozX INT, pozY INT)");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("ResultSet getTables/create table error: " + ex);
        }
    }
```

If I create a simple sample project on the same way as the above manual suggests, then the runtime runs properly. It seems it can not include only the jdbc/derby.

I thank you in advance for every suggestion to solve this really annoying issue.
Zed

Comment: If that `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);` call throws an exception, `conn` will be `null`, and then the line `dbmd = conn.getMetaData();` will give you a `NullPointerException`. So in addition to getting the Derby jars into your runtime package, make sure you address that error-checking in the DB code.

Comment: Ok Bryan, but how to tell to Jlink to put the derby / sql into the runtime?

Comment: Maybe it is better if I rephrase the question: How to tell Jlink to put a dependency into the runtime?

Comment: Sorry, I know very little about `jlink`. But I think that `jlink` has to do with **modules**, which are **not** the same as `jar` files in the `CLASSPATH`. Go here to read about modules: https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html I suspect that what you want is something more like what `maven` users call a "fat jar", but I am also not that familiar with Maven (I came to this question because it mentioned Derby)